# Google Analytics - PageView vs Sessions

Tags: session, google-analytics, hotspot, pageviews

I have simple question for my case. I have one HTML page on router witch serve as hotspot page. Also I have setup Analytics on that HTML page.
Question is when I want to deliver to a client number of users that visited that hotspot page, what should I use - PageViews or Sessions.
I notice that I have big difference between those two options.
example:
Sessions for 3 months: 1,050
PageViews for 3 moths: 15,501
Note: I only have one page on that hotspot..its not multi page its only one. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for webmasters.stackexchange.com or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GA, there's Users, Sessions, and Pageviews.

1 A user can have many sessions, 1 session can have many pageviews.

Out of the box, a user is defined by the cookie that's stored in the browser. If the cookie is deleted or of this physical user uses another browser, from GA's perspective it is a different user.

Sessions are started when a user visits your site and if their last "hit" sent to GA hasn't been over 30mins. The same thing with the cookie applies here. New session if the cookie is deleted (there are other cases where a new session will start, but for basics, you don't need to worry about them).

Pageviews are just that, every time someone views a page on your site, this count will increase. This will count refreshes, revisits, etc. There is also "unique pageviews" which only increment once per session.

Now, going back to which one you should use. Sessions or Pageviews won't tell you about users. Sessions will tell you how often people visit your site. Pageviews will tell you how often the page is loaded. If you want to tell users, you need to look at the users metric. Though do note the thing about cookies and cross devices.

If your site is authenticated, it is much easier to track individual accounts by utilizing the userID feature in GA.